# How to track dropout on first screen before tracking consent

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

It is known that users must explicitly consent the use of tracking tools like Google Analytics, Firebase etc. by the app, I am wondering if it possible to track dropouts on the first screen since as I understand analytics tracking can only be activated once the user allowed this when starting the app for the first time. I would like to know if there are users that exited the app on the first screen before consenting the tracking and decided to uninstall the app after that.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics for Firebase provides an API for [disabling Analytics collection](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics) temporarily before getting a user consent

***setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);***

You can log this as a event with int parameters 0 and 1 (or any other way you may want). Basically giving you the control and visibility of what you are looking for here.